# Automatically open a local file from webpage with given id

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, file, web

I would like to design a web service ( or a script embedded into a web page running on a local host) which accepts fileid as a parameter and then automatically open corresponding file in the same host.

for example if we enter http://localhost/openFile.aspx?id=JohnBrown to browser on a windows PC, it should automatically open file JohnBrown.ppsx stored in the hard drive.

Could you guide me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm thinking this would pose any number of security risks.

Comment: Well, this would assume the user has IIS installed and any other number of unlikely things. If its running off of localhost, why not use a desktop app?

Comment: yes there will be IIS running on the PC. We have our NFC tag reader application which only opens valid http urls. So we want to redirect request through a web page running on local host.

Answer (score 0):

`Server.Transfer` to desired page.